# Sklearn SGDClassifier minibatch-learning and learning rate schedule

Tags: scikit-learn, gradient-descent

I'm trying to piece together how the SGDClassifier picks its learning rate when I use the `partial_fit` method to train it.

I.e., my main learning loop looks like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
m = SGDClassifier(n_iter=1, alpha=0.01)
n_iter = 40
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(n_iter):
    for fname in files:
        X, y = load_next_batch(fname)
        m.partial_fit(X, y, classes = [0, 1])
    print "%d:  valid-error: %f  (time: %fs)" % (i, 1.0-m.score(Xvalid, yvalid), time.time() - t0)
```

now, since I make 40 passes through the whole training set, I'd like to anneal my learning rate over time. If i'd use `fit` instead of partial fit, it is my understanding that this would happen automatically (unless I'd modify the `learning_rate` parameter).

However, It is unclear to me how this happens when using partial fit. Skimming the code didn't help either. Could anyone clarify how I could achieve an annealed learning rate
in my setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fit` is using `partial_fit` internally, so the [learning rate configuration parameters](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) apply for both `fit` an `partial_fit`. The default annealing schedule is `eta0 / sqrt(t)` with `eta0 = 0.01`.

**Edit**: this is not correct, as seen in the comments the actual default schedule for `SGDClassifier` is:

`1.0 / (t + t0)` where `t0` is set heuristically and `t` is the number of samples seen in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I've noticed that eta0 is set to 0 by default (even though the documentation states it's 0.01) and remains such throughout the whole process. So I'm guessing that SGDClassifier somehow internally keeps track of the learning rate by other means.....  if I wanted to know what the learning rate is after 20 cycles through my training set, is there any way for me to query that?

Comment: The documentation is not up to date... in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/) you can see that for `SGDClassifier` the default learning rate schedule is called 'optimal' `1.0/(t+t0)` where `t0` is set from data; `eta0` is not used in this case. 

Also even for the 'invscaling' schedule , `eta0` is never updated: this is not the actual learning rate but only a way to pass the initial value.

In both case the progress of the schedule can be found in the attribute `model.t_` that gives the number of samples seen in the past.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I wasn't able to make sense of the code before :)